# Rummikub Joker After Replacement

Tags: rummikub

Tournament rules state that if a joker is in a meld one can not take from that meld. The joker can only be replaced with the tile the joker represented and used to make a meld with 2 tiles from your hand. So the question is after the required tile is placed (originally represented by the joker) can that meld be not be split or taken from for play?

(This question is not laid out in the rules as part of succession.)

Answer (score 2):

If the Joker has been replaced then there is no joker in the meld.  That would remove the condition of "If there is a joker in a meld..."

Maybe the key definition is that it says "is" not "was"

There are multiple different sets of rules for Rummikub, so it would be beneficial to link the rules being used if this answer does not suffice.